# Android - Listview API's

Tags: android

I am creating listview dyanamicaly in the code..Not through XML....!!

Two things i couldnt apply to the listview though code which i could apply through XML attributes.

```
1) android:divider="@android:color/transparent" 
2)  android:scrollbars="none"
```

What are the equivalent API's for these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are usually a pair of get and set methods with a similar name to the xml attribute. I believe the ones you want are `View#setVerticalScrollBarEnabled()` and `ListView#setDivider()`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVerticalScrollBarEnabled%28boolean%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDivider%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29

Comment: Thanks. View.SetVerticalScrollBarEnabled() worked. However i am still not able to set divider height.  I had set dividerHeight of 15 pixels gap between list items.Once i set setDivider() to transparent color, then there is not gap between list items.
How to avoid this ? I wanted a transparent background with a gap between list items.

Comment: Use a Drawable instead. You can create one and set the alpha to 0. Check it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for de divider.

```
setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
```

About the scrollbars I can't found anything. But if you adjust the content to the list size the scroollbar should not appear.